# gapi.auth2.signin() Success Callback not called on Mobile

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform

When I click on "Sign in with google" on desktop, it works perfectly, and I get a response with the `user` object. However, on mobile, I click on "Sign in with Google", but when I sign in, nothing happens. The `error` callback is called if I close the sign in tab. But if I log in successfully, the `success` callback is never called.

Here's the code I have:

```
async authenticate(): Promise<gapi.auth2.GoogleUser> {
    // Some google api intiazation stuff, nothing wrong here
    if (!this.gapiSetup) {
        await this.initiate();
    }
    
    return new Promise(async () => {
        await this.authInstance
            .signIn({
                prompt: 'select_account',
                ux_mode: 'popup'
            })
            .then(
                // this is called on desktop, NOT on mobile
                (user) => {
                    alert('connected');
                },
                
                // this is called on desktop AND mobile
                (error) => {
                    alert('Error connecting to google! 005x');
                });
    });
}
```

I've tried a couple of things, but to no avail: (Cleared Cookies), (Enabled popups and Javascript), (Wrapped `this.authInstance.signIn()` in a promise), ... a lot more things.

What's going on?

Comment: did you try in any other mobile browser?

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj No, I'll go try

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj On firefox, the popup doesn't show at all.

Comment: it could be due to permission, check permissions of browser.

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj I already had all permissions on allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i implemented google login using gapi, desktop web browsers also created some issues so i had to clear their data once then it started working so you should try once in a new browser and if it works there it was the issue of your browser only then. Clear the cache of the one you were using it should also work in it too.

Comment: Thanks, this works. After clearing the data, everything is working on desktop and mobile. The sad part, I'm logged out of everything.

Comment: Haha, i understand the pain! Kudos anyways.